# Change from /boot/efi to non boot/efi

Tags: partition, uefi

I have a Debian server A with given partition from `lsblk` and Debian server B with root partition.

I would like to convert server A same as server B. Basically I don't want the server A with `/boot/efi` partition. Can some experts guide how it can be achieved as this is a production server and baremetal.

Server A

```
sda 8:0 0 931.5G 0 disk
sdb 8:16 0 931.5G 0 disk
├─sdb1 8:17 0 512M 0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2 8:18 0 9.3G 0 part /
├─sdb3 8:19 0 7.5G 0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb4 8:20 0 18.6G 0 part /home
└─sdb5 8:21 0 55.9G 0 part /var
```

Server B

```
sda 8:0 0 931.5G 0 disk
sdb 8:16 0 931.5G 0 disk
|-sdb1 8:17 0 9.3G 0 part /
│-sdb2 8:18 0 7.5G 0 part [SWAP]
│-sdb3 8:19 0 1K 0 part
|-sdb5 8:21 0 18.6G 0 part /home
│-sdb6 8:22 0 57.9G 0 part /var
```

Haven't tried any method so far

Answer (score 1):

Server A is clearly using UEFI native boot method and GPT partitioning, which is the more future-proof of the two servers. On server A, you could use system disks larger than 2 TiB easily if needed.

The absence of the `/boot/efi` (or equivalent partition) and the presence of an 1K-sized `sdb3` (most likely a MBR extended partition) indicates server B is using legacy BIOS boot method and MBR partitioning. On MBR, a partition's maximum size is limited to 2 TiB and its starting point can be at most (2 TiB - 512 bytes) from the beginning of the disk (assuming classic 512-byte block size).

UEFI has been supported for more than 10 years now, and before COVID-19, Intel was planning to withdraw legacy BIOS compatibility support from year 2020 onward, but has apparently delayed these plans.

If Intel or some other chipset manufacturer releases a future x86 chipset which no longer presents the interfaces essential for booting within the first 1 MiB of physical address space, then classic 16-bit BIOS code might be difficult or impossible to implement for it, making the chipset fundamentally UEFI-only.

There are already UEFI-only server models on the market, and as time passes, more and more server models will become UEFI-only. As a result, converting server A to legacy-style for the sake of uniformity only would probably result in having to convert both of them to UEFI at the next hardware refresh, instead of just one. I think this would not be a good idea.

---

But if you really want to do it, downtime is definitely required:

- back up all user data and configuration, just to be safe
- reboot the system, go to firmware settings (BIOS settings)
- disable Secure Boot, enable legacy Compatibility Support Module (CSM); if possible, configure the system to boot in *legacy mode only* to prevent mistakes
- boot from some live Linux media, and use it to record the exact start/end/length block values for each partition.
- use `gdisk` expert command `z`ap (i.e. `x` then `z`) to zero the GPT partition table and its backup, then create a new MBR partition table, reproducing exactly the partitions you'll want to keep, using the information recorded earlier. You might have to reduce the size of the swap partition by just a little to create space for the extended partition record.
- verify the kernel has accepted the new partition table, e.g. by checking `/proc/partitions`; use `partprobe` if necessary to refresh the kernel's idea of the partitioning
- chroot into the system disk you're converting, and ensure all the partitions are mountable and error-free as MBR partitions. Update `/etc/fstab`. If you had to reduce the swap partition, remember to re-`mkswap` it, adjust the swap UUID in `/etc/fstab` and update the initramfs.
- while chrooted, remove any `efibootmgr` and `grub-efi-*` packages and install packages `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin`: run `grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdb` to install a BIOS version of GRUB explicitly
- reboot and go into BIOS settings, verify the boot order; adjust if necessary
- done

If you have any sort of scripted installation procedure, a full reinstall may be faster and less error-prone.

Chrooting from live media into the system disk under conversion would be something like this:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt   # the root filesystem under conversion
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -t proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
mount /var
mount /home
```

and at this point, you can run commands essentially as if already booted into the system that is being converted.

Comment: Laptop vendors are now UEFI only. Lenovo announced all 2020 products will be UEFI only (UEFI Class 3 or no CSM).
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510878-legacy-bios-boot-support-removed-in-lenovo-2020-products My Dell with 11th Gen Intel chip is also UEFI only, but Dell still calls it BIOS?

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for providing information although some complicated task.....These servers are pretty old and are in production so have to work as it is..

Comment: @telcoM  So deleting and creating new MBR partition is the only way ? Will i be able to restore all data after creating new table?

Comment: When you delete the GPT partition table, the data will still be still on the disk. If you can exactly reproduce the start/end locations of each partition you wish to keep in a new MBR partition table, you will find that you will be able to access those filesystems as MBR partitions with no need to restore anything. But because GPT partition table has a backup at the end of the disk, you must wipe both the main and backup GPT so the system won't recognize the disk as GPT-partitioned any more. `gdisk`'s `z`ap command is an easy way to do exactly that.